How to Include Test Runtime in the HTML Coverage File?
There is the overview in the terminal after running a test that looks something like this:
============= 7 passed in 6.96s ==============
As well as a header in the HTML Coverage file that begins like this:
Coverage for <SCRIPT>: 75%
I am currently calling the pytest script like this:
pytest test_<SCRIPT>.py --cov-report=html
Ideally I would like to modify the header of the HTML file so it looks something like this:
Coverage for <SCRIPT>: 75% in 6.96s
But I would be satisfied with the runtime being in any predictable location in the HTMl file, as I am running similar tests on many scripts in my repository and want to extract the runtime of each programmatically after I have run each of them for a report.
If anyone can tell me of a way to include the runtime in the HTML output I would be very appreciative. Thank you!
I found this thread but I do not think it is exactly what I want:
How to access the overall runtime in pytest?

Does the runtime need to be part of your coverage report or would it be ok to have a reliable way to read the runtime?

runtime must be a part of my report. currently I am saving a log file of the terminal output and reading the terminal output. not the most elegant method but currently works
